# Using bash script output with periodic output selectively to trigger another script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I have a python script that probes a motion sensor every few seconds and returns a value on the shell "**sensor is off**" or "**sensor is on**"

Next, I created a bash script as follows called `sensor.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash
sudo python /home/pi/ouimeaux/ouimeaux/examples/watch.py "Wemo Motion"
```

Then I tried doing the following to activate `trigger.sh` if the output stream says "**sensor is on**"

```
./sensor.sh 2>&1 >/dev/null | grep “on”
if [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
/etc/init.d/trigger.sh start
else
echo "do nothing"
fi
```

However, it does not seem to work - I assumed that the `stdout` redirect would work.

I understand I could write the output to a log file and have another script read the tail to do this but, this script runs on a Raspberry Pi and I would prefer keeping disk writes less.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

`2&1` merges stderr into stdout, but then you discard stdout with `> /dev/null`,  so grep never sees any input. So, as a direct solution to your problem, take out the /dev/null redirect.

However, a better solution still would be to modify your python script to return a different exit status depending on sensor value, then use that status in an if statement directly, which cuts grep out of the equation entirely

```
if ./sensor.sh &>/dev/null; then
    /etc/init.d/trigger.sh start
else
    echo "do nothing"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You test the grep *exit code*. But **grep won't exit until you stream ends**.

You can do this approach:

```
stream.py | while read line; do
  if ["$line" = "sensor on"]; then
    echo ON
  fi
done
```

You might be tempted to do

```
if echo $line | grep -q on; then
```

But that will fork even more processes.

It's much more efficient to do that in python right away.